# Statistics of call XREFs

Tags: ida

Is it possible to see a kind of statistics in IDA about functions and how often they are referenced? When analyzing a program, I find it helpfull.

Functions that are referenced very often typically are common functionality. An example would be stuff like `strcmp()`, `malloc()/free()`, `strlen()`, etc..

Some of those are quite easy to identfiy (like  a `strcmp()` implementation), and giving a name to those functions early on, makes the analysis of the rest more easy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There might be an easier way to get the count XrefsTo a certain function, but this worked for me.

```
from idaapi import *
funcs = Functions()
for f in funcs:
   name = Name(f)
   print "%s %d" % (name, len(list(XrefsTo(f))))
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code is taken from GreyHat Python, and is very similar to the previous answer:

```
from idaapi import *
funcs = ["malloc","free","strcmp"]

for f in funcs:
   curAddr = LocByName(f)
   if curAddr != BADADDR:
      xrefs = CodeRefsTo(curAddr,0)
      print "Cross References to %s" % f
      for ref in xrefs:
         print "08x" % ref
         SetColor(ref,CIC_ITEM,0x0000ff)
```

This function will also highlight the call to make tracing it easier

Comment: This assumes the functions are already named, while @Devolus wants to identify these common functions (when the names are not known yet) by first inspecting functions with high XREF counts.

Comment: I know, but I thought the information might still come in handy.